# Getting names and values from a list on to different graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data set and list that I have been working with. I have been trying to create a separate graph for each `ID` in my list `l`. I would like to print `A = 1` in a graph for `A`, `B = 2` in a graph for `B`, etc. In my actual data set the `ID`s are repeated throughout the list different values, and ideally I would like to have all the values for one `ID` from the list printed on the graph associated that `ID`.

This is what I have tried before, but when I try to see the plots I get the error

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (200): label
```

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy_hms("01-01-2010 12:01:01"), dmy_hms("31-12-2013 01:59:59"), by = "days"),1000)
ID <- rep(c("A","B","C", "D", "E"), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID, NSD = runif(length(date), min = 0, max = 100000))

l <- list(1,2,4,3,5)

df1 <- df %>% group_split(ID)
names(l) <- sapply(df1, function(x) x$ID[1])

id_labels <- tibble(
  ID = names(l),
  id_val = l
) %>% 
  # make desired labels for each facet
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(label = paste(ID, id_val, sep = ": ", collapse = '\n'))


# Plot NSD
p.list <- lapply(sort(unique(df$ID)), function(i){
  ggplot(df[df$ID == i,], aes(x = date, y = NSD)) + 
    geom_line() + theme_bw() + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
    scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '10 days', date_labels = '%y%j') +
    facet_grid( ~ ID, scales = "free") +
    scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(seq(15,365,length.out=4)[match(i, sort(unique(df$ID)))], 100, 65)) +
    geom_text(aes(x=min(date),y=max(NSD),label=paste0("EMD ",id_labels$label)),
              size = 2)
})
```

Any thoughts on what I could do to get this output?

Comment: Are you trying to create a `facet_grid` by `ID` or have a single plot for each `ID` stored in a list?

Comment: Your posted example has several errors. Try running your code in a fresh session and edit your question to debug your example.

Comment: It should be fixed now, aside from the error message that I have been getting with `ggplot`. I am trying to have a single plot for each ID stored in a list. I have another list `l` that has the `ID` and values and I want to print the values from the list `l` based on the `ID` those values are assigned to. In my actual data set, the `ID` is repeated multiple times in the list, and have different values with the same `ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your reproducible example you could do this:

```
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)

p.list <- imap(split(df, ID), ~ 
                 ggplot(.x, aes(x = date, y = NSD)) + 
                 geom_line() +
                 theme_bw() + 
                 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
                 scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = '2 months', date_labels = '%y%j') +
                 geom_text(data = subset(id_labels, ID == .y), aes(label = label,
                                               x = as.POSIXct(-Inf, '1970-01-01'),
                                               y = max(.x$NSD),
                                               hjust = 0, 
                                               vjust = 0))
                 )
```

**How it works**

1. `split` splits your dataframe into a list based on `ID`.
2. `purrr::imap` iterates over a named list storing the element of the list as `.x` and the name of that element as `.y`.
3. I've left a few layers out of your ggplot for simplicity, but you can add those back in.
4. The trouble you are probably having is trying to put a label on your graph when the x-scale is a date. The way you do that is using `hjust` and `vjust`, but in order to not throw an error the x-coordinate still has to be `POSIXct`.

You can try adjusting the values of `hjust` and `vjust` to move your label around.

**Output**

```
p.list$A
```

[image]